# SparseIntArray doesn't change when being tested with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

I'm new to `Robolectric` and I'm trying to unit test a simple getter/setter code, but it seems that the `SparseIntArray` isn't working as expected when testing with `Robolectric` and it simply doesn't change. (i always get '0' with the get method).

I also tried adding a static getter for the `SparseIntArray` itself and found out that after calling the setter, the array size is 0.

what am I missing here ?

this is the code I'm trying to test:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static SparseIntArray sRequestStatus;

public static int getStatus(int request) {
    return sRequestStatus.get(request);
}

public static void setStatus(int request, int status) {
    if (sRequestStatus.get(request) != 0) {
        sRequestStatus.delete(request);
        sRequestStatus.put(request, status);
    } else {
        sRequestStatus.put(request, status);
    }
}

    static {
    sRequestStatus = new SparseIntArray();
    }
}
```

and this is the test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyClassTests {

@Test
public void testGetSetStatus() throws Exception {
    // get status should return 0 for non-exisiting request
    assertEquals(0, MyClass.getStatus(1));

    // set status should add a request mapping
    MyClass.setStatus(1, 1);
    assertEquals(1, MyClass.getStatus(1));

    // set status should change the request status if mapping exists
    MyClass.setStatus(1, 2);
    assertEquals(2, MyClass.getStatus(1));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to get-delete-put in setStatus, put will replace existing value anyway. See the doc on put: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html

Comment: there is a button to say that ;) but it didn't fix your problem right?

Comment: no it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out there wasn't a Shadow for `SparseIntArray` in the version of `Robolectric` I was using..